# Replacement for wait() in Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library, testing-library

I've recently updated the version of testing-library in a react/typescript project. I have found that the following statement is no longer part of the package:

```
import { wait } from '@testing-library/user-event/dist/utils';
```

> Cannot find module '@testing-library/user-event/dist/utils' or its
> corresponding type declarations.

It was used in the following way:

```
await wait();
```

I cannot find any documentation on what replaced this functionality or where it is located. The closest I can find is a `waitFor` method but it is not clear how the two functions differ.

Comment: What's the version of the `user-event` package before upgrading?

Comment: @LinDu  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0"

Comment: Found `wait` function here `import { wait } from "@testing-library/user-event/utils/misc/wait";`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately they don't appear to be exactly the same as that wait has a mandatory parameter. I'll look into it further though - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What is it that you're waiting for? `waitFor` should be used for waiting for functions to be called and "normal" `await` when performing user events like clicks and typing

Answer (score 1):

In this case, user-event has a `wait` function that is an implementation detail and is not part of the public API.  The risk you run when you use functions that aren't considered part of the public API (it isn't exported from the index, mentioned in the documentation, etc), is that they may change, be moved, or even eliminated entirely.

I recommend using `waitFor`.  The `wait` function used to be part of the dom-testing-library API, but as of version 7 of dom-testing-library, it was replaced with `waitFor` (see the [release notes](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/releases/tag/v7.0.0) and [official API docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)).  However, your intended use case, `await waitFor();` is discouraged by the library's creator (see [Common Mistakes With React Testing Library](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#passing-an-empty-callback-to-waitfor)).

Ideally, you should wait for something specific to happen:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo'));
expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```